how to setup one concept for template member method with boost::type_erasure?
I have one class as below
struct AA
{
  template <class U>
  bool is_flag()
  {
    /*some logic*/
    return true;
  }
};

I try to setup one boost::type_erasure concept as the example with following code:
template <class T, class U>
struct has_is_flag
{
  static bool apply(T &sm, U)
  {
    return sm.is_flag<U>();
  }
};
struct BB {};

AA aa;
BB bb;
//_a is placeholder, its real type is passed when call function is executed.
boost::type_erasure::any<has_is_flag<_self, _a>, _self&> c(aa);
bool ret = call(has_is_flag<_self, _a>,c,bb);

but the compiler reports the last line is wrong with message:

'call': no matching overloaded function found

I have no idea how to fix it. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Please include the self-contained example that you're compiling
